# .htaccess returns 500 Internal Server Error when slash on filename

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file has a rewrite in it so instead of seeing `example.com/login.php`, one will see `example.com/login`.

Here is what is written in that file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

It works perfectly except for one thing: I am creating a file called `api.php` that will serve as the api.
I want clients to go to `example.com/api/logout` and `example.com/api/auth` etc. even though `api` is not a folder but instead a PHP file.

Problem is, whenever I go to a file like `example.com/api/logout` (or even `example.com/login/foo`), I always get a 500 Internal Server Error. If I go to `example.com/api.php/logout`, I get a 404 error.

I checked the error file for the 500 Internal Server Error, and it says `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error` which makes sense because mod_rewrite runs until all conditions are satisfied.

How should I change my rewrite to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> :  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
> ```

When you request a URL of the form `/api/logout` you will get a rewrite loop (500 error) because the `REQUEST_FILENAME` maps to `<document-root>/api` (which if you append `.php` is indeed a valid file), but you end up appending `.php` to `/api/logout` (the URL-path) in the `RewriteRule` directive (clearly not the same thing). `/api/logout.php` then gets rewritten to `/api/logout.php.php` etc. etc. repeatedly appending `.php` to the URL-path, while all the time checking that `/api.php` is a valid file.

If all your files are in the document root, then you can change your `RewriteRule` *pattern* to only match the first path segment. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) $1.php [L]
```

However, if you have files at different directory depths (which you are referencing without the `.php` extension) then you might need to create some specific rules / exceptions.

> If I go to `example.com/api.php/logout`, I get a 404 error.

This will result in a 404 if *additional pathname information* (PATH_INFO) has been disabled (although it is usually enabled by default for PHP files). You can explicitly enable this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```